# How to get specific words by index in a line bash

Tags: bash, shell, text

I have a script that takes parameters such as:

```
script.sh 1 3
```

I want to then go through a text file and print out the first and third words from each line. I have simply no idea how to do this. If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it...

This is what I currently have:

```
counter=0
wordcounter=0

param=$(echo "$3" | tr , " ") 

words(){
    for word in $1; do
        for col in $param; do
            if [ $wordcounter -eq $col ]; then
                echo $word
            fi
        done 
    done
    wordcounter=$((wordcounter + 1))
}

eachline() {
    newline=$(echo "$1" | tr , " ")
    for word in $newline; do
        if [ $counter -gt 3 ]; then
            echo "$word"
        fi
        counter=$((counter + 1))
    done
    if [ $counter -gt 0 ]; then 
        words "$newline"
    fi
    counter=$((counter + 1))
}

while read line; do
    eachline $line
done < company/employee.txt
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm currently trying to make a second script that takes a line as parameter, then running each line from the file into the script.

Comment: In the script itself I'm setting a counter and ignoring the number of words in the first line

Comment: It's very very very hacky

Comment: Will `cut -d " " -f 1,3 file` do?

Answer (score 3):

Use `awk`:

```
$ awk '{print $1 " " $3}' file
```

for `file`:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
```

Output is:

```
1 3
6 8
```

In bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk_command="{print";
for i in "$@"; do
    awk_command="${awk_command} \$${i} \" \"";
done    
awk_command="${awk_command}}";
awk "$awk_command" file
```

With this script you can pass any number of indexes:

For 1 and 2:

```
$ ./script.sh 1 2
1 2 
6 7
```

For 1, 2 and 5:

```
$ ./script.sh 1 2 5
1 2 5 
6 7 0
```